# How to start? HTML designed email in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, outlook

I would like to create a Survey Form (it is about how satisfied the managers are with the employees).

I would like to create it in HTML, because I have to insert an image in the form and I will need option buttons as well.

How can I type HTML code in Outlook 2013? I can't find the function to edit or create HTML.

[image]

Comment: you may want to look at this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-polls-in-e-mail-messages-and-review-the-results-4d10e079-8ea1-489a-a79c-18cb71ae12dd

Comment: Creating HTML emails is tough, I certainly wouldn't recommend using Outlook to create one, you may get it to look ok in outlook but every email client (Gmail, Hotmail, AOL Mail, Yahoo Mail, Thunderbird, Apple Mail Live Mail to name a few.) will all display the email differently. Check out:  https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/ and http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-you-should-know-about-html-email--webdesign-12908 

Creating a form will be tough too https://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/

Maybe look into using Mailchimp and SurveyMonkey

Comment: I would like to send this mail to Outlook 2010 and 2013 only.